# How to make pagination through a SharePoint 2013 list view with GetItems and GetItemsInFolder?

Tags: development, paging

I am developing a WCF service that retrieve items from SharePoint 2013 (Server Side Model), through views:

```
var list = web.Lists[someLibGuid];//Document Library List
var view = list.Views[0];
var folder = web.GetFolder(someFolderGuid);
var items = list.GetItems(view);
var itemsInFolder = ((SPDocumentLibrary)list).GetItemsInFolder(view, folder);
```

By default both GetItems and GetItemsInFolder will retrieve the default rowlimit(let's say 30 items)

How to get **next page**(next 30 items) or Page with index X through this **specific view** ?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement that using caml query and [SPListItemCollectionPosition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitemcollectionposition.aspx), to know more about the implementation, kindly have a look at the below links,

1. [SharePoint List Pagination using SPListItemCollectionPosition](http://sharepoint.infoyen.com/2012/03/06/sharepoint-list-pagination-using-splistitemcollectionposition/)
2. [Learning SharePoint Part VII – List Pagination](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/colbyafrica/2009/02/19/learning-sharepoint-part-vii-list-pagination/)

Comment: Thanks for your effort, i knew how to use SPListItemCollectionPosition by caml query, but problem is how to apply it to a view as mentioned in the question, i have an idea by using the SPListItemCollectionPosition on the SPView.Query, but i am not sure if this is best practice and if it will conserve the view criterias (where, sorting, grouping). One more thing there is a property in the SPView called Paged (bool), but i couldn't find an example how to use it, let say i set it true then how i can call next page.