# AJAX: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: javascript, development, jquery, ajax

I am developing a visual web part and I am trying to some list items on demand. With this in mind I have created a WebService named `CommentFetchSvc.asmx` and added the following code:

```
public class CommentFetchSvc : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    public CommentFetchSvc()
    {
        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }

    public class BlogItem
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
    }

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public List<BlogItem> ReadComments(string pagenum)
    {
        List<BlogItem> blogList = new List<BlogItem>();

        using (SPSite oSpSite = new SPSite("http://mysiteUrl"))
        {
            using (SPWeb oSpWeb = oSpSite.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPList oList = oSpWeb.Lists["LageData"];
                SPQuery oQuery = new SPQuery();

                int pageNum = int.Parse(pagenum);
                // Number of rows to fetch
                oQuery.RowLimit = 5;

                // Start reading from 1
                int intIndex = 1;
                do
                {
                    SPListItemCollection collListItems = oList.GetItems(oQuery);

                    // Check if this are the records to be returned
                    if (intIndex == pageNum)
                    {
                        // Read items for the specific range
                        foreach (SPListItem oListItem in collListItems)
                        {
                            BlogItem item = new BlogItem();
                            item.Title = oListItem["Title"].ToString();
                            item.Body = oListItem["ID"].ToString();
                            blogList.Add(item);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    oQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition = collListItems.ListItemCollectionPosition;
                    intIndex++;
                }
                while (oQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition != null);
            }
        }
        return blogList;
    }
}
```

I created and sent WebService in `_layouts/15/Load5MoreComments`. When I enter the url of WebService it loads successfully and I can see my methods:
[image: webservice]

then I am trying to call `ReadComments` from ajax with following code:

```
<asp:HiddenField Value="1" id="pageTrack" runat="server"></asp:HiddenField>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">       
$(document).ready(LoadData());

function LoadData() {
    GetCommentItems();
}

function GetCommentItems() {
    var pageTrack = $("input[id$='pageTrack']").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/_layouts/15/Load5MoreComments/CommentFetchSvc.asmx/ReadComments",
        type: "POST",
        data: "{'pagenum':'" + pageTrack + "'}",
        contentType: 'application/json;',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (msg) {
            AppendItems(msg);
            var newPageTrack = $("input[id$='pageTrack']").val();
            $("input[id$='pageTrack']").val(parseInt(newPageTrack) + 1);
        },
        error: function (xhr, msg) {
            console.log(msg + '\n' + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });

    function AppendItems(data) {
        $.each(data.d, function (i, item) {
            var title = item.Title;
            var body = item.Body;
            html = '<li><b>' + title + '</b></li>';
            html += body;
            html += '<hr/>';
            $('#resultarea').append($(html));
        });
    }
}
</script>

 <p>

<asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl='javascript:void(0);' id="lnkMore" onClick="GetCommentItems();" runat="server">View next five comments..</asp:HyperLink>
</p>
```

BUT I AM GETTING THE FOLLOWING ERROR `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Although when I click `ReadComments` link in my WebService from the browser it works perfect and when I fill the pagenum parameter it shows my data. But AJAX won't call the method.
[image: webservice]

When I enter `1 in my pagenum parameter`:
[image]

Please HELP ME.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a SOAP Service, so try sending XML instead of JSON. Something like:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/_layouts/15/Load5MoreComments/CommentFetchSvc.asmx",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "xml",
  beforeSend: function(xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader('SOAPAction', 'http://tempuri.org/ReadComments'); },
  data: '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><ReadComments xmlns="http://tempuri.org"><pagenum>'+pageTrack+'</pagenum></ReadComments></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>',
  contentType: 'text/xml; charset=utf-8',
  success: function (msg) {
    console.log(msg)
  },
  error: function (xhr, msg) {
    console.log(msg + '\n' + xhr.responseText);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer but I am getting the following error: `error
Request format is invalid: text/xml; charset=UTF-8.` I changed to following line to return `XML`  `[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml)]`

Comment: I've updated my answer by changing the endpoint url and by adding ` dataType`. Try with them. If it still doesn't work, then I don't know, because this is how to deal with the standard Sharepoint SOAP services.

Comment: I am getting a new error: `Unable to handle request without a valid action parameter. Please supply a valid soap action.`

Comment: Sorry I misread the screen capture. You also need to add a header `SOAPAction` to your request. See my edited answer. All of these things are explained when you go to `/_layouts/15/Load5MoreComments/CommentFetchSvc.asmx/ReadComments`

Comment: thanks for your comment but I am getting again a new error: `Server was unable to process request. ---&gt; Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: String`

Comment: Verify you have something into `pageTrack`.

Comment: I manually did this: `var pageTrack = 1;` but still same error

Comment: I think that the error is in parameters, I have called the `HelloWorld` method which has no parameters and worked successfully.

Comment: I figured out after debugging  that whatever the parameter value is, its value always is going null when calling the method. i.e now I have this `<pagenum>5</pagenum>` but on server side after debugging this value is null. I even tried this: `<pagenum>testSte</pagenum>` but again its null in server side.